# riot.js tag removed during compilation breaking style

Tags: riot.js

Using [Yeoman rtjs generator](https://github.com/joelchu/generator-rtjs).  Very basic example using rollup.js and [rollup-plugin-riot](https://github.com/riot/rollup-plugin-riot).

Tag is very simple:

```
<home>
    <div class="card" id="home-card">
        <div class="card-block">
            <a href="https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com">
                <h1>Bootstrap 4 starter template</h1>
            </a>
            <p class="lead">
                Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.
                <br />
                All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <style>
        #home-card {
            margin-top: 65px;
        }
    </style>
</home>
```

However, the HTML produced lacks the `<home>` tag:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="card" id="home-card">
        <div class="card-block"><a href="https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com"><h1>Bootstrap 4 starter template
        </h1>
        </a>
            <p class="lead"> Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project. <br> All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thus, this included style doesn't work:

```
<style type="text/css">
    home #home-card,[data-is="home"] #home-card{ margin-top: 65px; }
</style>
```

This is probably something simple/basic, but as a riot.js newbie, I'm not seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize this was a virtual tag:

```
<div class="container">
    <virtual data-is={component}></virtual>
</div><!-- /.container -->
```

This removes the `<home>` tag